# Requested texture dimensions JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

When I try to create a very **large polygon** in JavaFX to use it with a camera perspective, I have some trouble with the **GPU memory**. When I try to use it without a camera and subscene, I have the same problem. I have a problem with Runtime Exception.

**Java 8:**

I went from a Java 8 version to a Java 11 version to try to find some patch. In version 8 of Java, with bundled JavaFX, I was got a Null Pointer Exception when the GPU memory (on my laptop 3072MB) overtaken.

- width x height x 32 bits to MB
- 10000x10000x32/1024/1024 = 3051 MB (Ok)
- 11000*11000*32/1024/1024 = 3692MB >  3072MB (Crash)

**Java 11:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested texture dimensions (22022x42) require dimensions (0x42) that exceed maximum texture size (16384)
```

My current environment is Java 11 with JavaFX 12-ea+3.

```
    /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1/bin/java --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/97/lib/idea_rt.jar=40539:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/97/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/walter/amzpls/target/classes:/home/walter/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.6.4/mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/12-ea+3/javafx-controls-12-ea+3.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/12-ea+3/javafx-controls-12-ea+3-linux.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/12-ea+3/javafx-fxml-12-ea+3.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/12-ea+3/javafx-fxml-12-ea+3-linux.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/12-ea+3/javafx-graphics-12-ea+3.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/12-ea+3/javafx-graphics-12-ea+3-linux.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/12-ea+3/javafx-base-12-ea+3.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/12-ea+3/javafx-base-12-ea+3-linux.jar -p /home/walter/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/12-ea+3/javafx-base-12-ea+3-linux.jar:/home/walter/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/12-ea+3/javafx-graphics-12-ea+3-linux.jar ca.amzpls.app.FXMain
java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested texture dimensions (22022x22022) require dimensions (0x0) that exceed maximum texture size (16384)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2RTTexture.create(ES2RTTexture.java:220)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2ResourceFactory.createRTTexture(ES2ResourceFactory.java:157)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGShape.renderContent(NGShape.java:234)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGSubScene.renderContent(NGSubScene.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested texture dimensions (22022x22022) require dimensions (0x0) that exceed maximum texture size (16384)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2RTTexture.create(ES2RTTexture.java:220)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2ResourceFactory.createRTTexture(ES2ResourceFactory.java:157)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGShape.renderContent(NGShape.java:234)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGSubScene.renderContent(NGSubScene.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Simple Polygone Square 11000x11000 based on coordinates (0;0;0)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Box box = new Box(1500, 1500, 500);

        // init camera
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        camera.setFarClip(10000);
        camera.setTranslateZ(-1000);


        // large polygon
        Polygon h = new Polygon();
        h.getPoints().addAll(0d, 0d, 11000d, 0d, 11000d, 11000d, 0d, 11000d);
        h.setStroke(Color.RED);
        h.setStrokeWidth(10);
        h.setTranslateZ(100);

        Group root3D = new Group(box, h);

        SubScene subScene = new SubScene(root3D, 1200, 1200, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        subScene.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);
        subScene.setCamera(camera);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(subScene);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("3D SubScene");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I have another problem when the polygon belongs to Plan X, Y at 0 Z-Axis.

- The polygon doesn't appear if the polygon is bigger than the
  window in Java 11.
- The polygon doesn't completely appear if the polygon is bigger than the window in Java 8.

**Context to not appear totaly**

```
h.setTranslateZ(0);
```

**Java 8 screenshot**

[image]

**Some way toward answering**

- The requested texture issue can be "fix" with `-Dprism.targetvram=2G`

**Investigation**

I know the problem comes to texturing of the polygon shape. But I don't want to texture it. So, why I can't be able to draw a big polygon shape without texture and without a crash. This is a bad approach from me, to drawing big polygon shapes with a simple background color. Or JavaFX architecture does not support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I am going to notice that, It was **my first usage of JavaFX**.

So, I think I fold in lack of knowledge of this technology and overrate the basic proposals of the 3D Scene.

**Where is the problem?**

I want to draw a polygon in my 3DScene with the 2D Polygon Class in JavaFX. Because It's effortless to handle mouse event and position with a little unprojection. Moreover, when I do it, my program takes a lot of GRAM/RAM.

**Why?**

Because of the Polygone based on the 2D JavaFX application context and consequently create a texture to handle the JavaFX CSS, as a texture applies on the polygon. So, if you expect to draw 10k by 10k square polygon by the 2D Polygon Class, you create a texture to handle 10k by 10k pixels and as well as the array memory.

**Conclusion**

The primaries 2D shapes are no shaped to be handled in the 3D scene. For example, if you want to write a simple 2D blueprint builder with JavaFX and the CameraPerspective don't use 2D shape to handle it.